# Copy Files from Network Drive in Windows 2008 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share

I have a job to copy files from a network drive to my local Windows 2008 server box. For most files the job works fine; however, for a specific job, I constantly get failure. It seems related to the file size (20MB).

For example, I dropped the file from a mapped network drive to my local drive. As soon as release the file, I got a warning dialog:

[image]

After a while, I got the following failure error:
[image]

I also tried to use XCOPY from command line. I got the similar error ("The specified network name is no longer avaivalable"). Actually from the File explorer, I could see files on the network drive after I got the above failures. I think it may be something else related to Windows security settings. Not sure where I could configure/change those settings.

By the way, for smaller size files, I have no issue to copy files from the same network drive.

Comment: Have you tried transferring any other large files?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the "The [mapped network drive n:] is no longer available" when copying one or two files to `c:\inetput\wwwroot\[webfolder]`, even though the mapped drive *is* available. These files are <25K, not like your 20MB example.

However, I can get the file copy to go smoothly if I first copy to a folder on the desktop, and then copy from desktop folder to `c:\inetput\wwwroot\[webfolder]`

At least... that was the behavior *yesterday*. Today, a straight-copy is working fine. ?!?!??